# changing a div's visibility through a button click/hover html

Tags: html, css

disclaimer: i am new to html and don't know javascript so if possible to do only using html and css.
also not native english and this is my first ever question on stack overflow so thank for your patience.

i have a div containing a list that should not be visible. i have a button that should display the div whenever i click it or hover it.

the problem is:
-if the div is outside the button tag the hover thing doesn't work but the div looks perfect

[div with list outside the button tag](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vz3f7.png)

-if the div is inside the button tag the hover "function" works but if i move to slowly i can't select any of the items from the list because it seems to me there is a little space between the button and the div; also the div looks weird like this:
[div with list inside the button tag](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WDFm7.png)

this should be the code:

```css
  <style>
.total{
  margin-left: 61px;
  margin-right: 61px;
  height:100vh;
}
.meniu{
  position:absolute;
  top:0px;
  right:0px;
  height:61px;
  width:61px;
}


*{
  margin:0;
  padding:0;
}

.lista-container{
  background-color: lightgreen;
width:auto;
height:auto;
position:absolute;
top:61px;
right:15px;
border:solid black 2px;
display:none;
}

ul{
  list-style: none;
  font-size:20px;
  color: black;
  line-height: 40px;
}
ul li a{
  text-decoration:none;
  display:block;
}
ul li a:hover{
  background-color:lightblue;
}

.meniu:hover .lista-container{
  display:block;
}

      </style>
```

```html
<body>

<div class="total" >
<button class="meniu" >Menu
  <div class="lista-container">
    <ul>
      <li><a href="#">Arcul de Triumf</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Ateneul Roman</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Casa Poporului</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Muzeul Antipa</a></li>

    </ul>
  </div>
</button>


</div>



    </body>
```

been struggling with this for like 2 days thanks.

Comment: You should not use a `button` if you not firing a script with it. A button is an element that is sued a trigger for a script.

Answer (score 0):

Since you do nos cripting, you should remove the button which is a trigger to fire a script.

Then you have in CSS no selector to recognize if a button was clicked. A CSS-Solution would be to use a `checkbox` which can use a pseudo-selector `:checked`:

```css
#button {
  display: none;
}

.total {
  margin-left: 61px;
  margin-right: 61px;
  height: 100vh;
}

.meniu {
  border: 1px solid black;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0px;
  right: 0px;
  height: 61px;
  width: 61px;
}

* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

.lista-container {
  background-color: lightgreen;
  width: min-content;
  white-space: nowrap;
  height: auto;
  position: absolute;
  top: 61px;
  right: 15px;
  border: solid black 2px;
  display: none;
}

ul {
  list-style: none;
  font-size: 20px;
  color: black;
  line-height: 40px;
}

ul li a {
  text-decoration: none;
  display: block;
}

ul li a:hover {
  background-color: lightblue;
}

.meniu:hover .lista-container,
#button:checked + .meniu > .lista-container {
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<div class="total">
  <input type="checkbox" id="button">
  <label for="button" class="meniu">Menu
    <div class="lista-container">
      <ul>
        <li><a href="#">Arcul de Triumf</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Ateneul Roman</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Casa Poporului</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Muzeul Antipa</a></li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </label>
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you so much. It  works perfectly. However , the list has it's text appearing on 2 rows. EX:   instead of Arcul de Triumf      i get   'Arcul' and 'de Triumf' is below even if still in the same list element box. Is there any way to change that so the text is displayed like in the image "div with list ouside the button" that i included in my queston?  Thanks again for the help!

Comment: becaue you set the width to 61px in your CSS (`.meniu { width: 61px; }`). As such a linebreak will accure because the text is wider then the the container.

Comment: changing the list container width from auto to pixels measurment worked.Thanks for your patience again.

Comment: no you have to change the width of the div which is set to `auto` which means it will take the width of the parent element ( `.meniu`). So you specififcally have to set the width on that div to overwrite the width from the parent element. One easy solution would be `width: min-content; white-space: nowrap` which makes the width as wide as necessary without line-break;

Comment: oh that makes a lot of sense thank you so much